# 500 Internal Server Error with PDO connecting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, internal-server-error

I'm connecting to a MySQL database with PHP, and in the beginning I used the mysql_ methods. I then found out that these methods are deprecated, so I've switched to PDO, and am now in the midst of changing my code (and I don't have any experience with PHP PDO). Now I'm getting an error and I (and also my colleague) cannot figure out why I get it, and the code is very straightforward, so I'm not sure..

I have a script that configures connection variables like this:

```
    <?php
define('DB_USER', "user"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', "password"); // db password
define('DB_DATABASE', "myDB"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server
?>
```

Then I've defined a class for connecting to the database:

```
 <?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT {
   private $con;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->con = null;
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        try {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_DATABASE.";charset=utf8mb4", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $this->con -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         return $con;

        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die("Error connecting to DB: ".$ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now I'm running this next script, which fetches all items from one table in my database:

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();
// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ITEM") or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM ITEM";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query); //eror here!

$stmt -> execute();

//foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM ITEM") as $row) {
//    $response["products"] = array();
//}




// check for empty result
if ($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0 ) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row =$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["am"] = $row["am"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Basic rule: If you get a 500 error from a website, your FIRST stop on the debugging train will be to go look at the webserver's error log. Until you get details about the error, anything you do is just flailing around in the dark, GUESS at the problem.

Comment: Notice you are returning `return $con;` not `return $this->con;`

Comment: can I recommend to you an answer with my class structure of php PDO that I use in my applications?

Comment: Proper syntax would be `$this->con` instead of `$this->$con` in this context.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you @MarcB . So it says: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: con in db_connect.php on line 29 and  PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in db_connect.php on line 29.
Is it because I've instantialized the variable 'con' (on line: private $con), but not initialized it, so it is empty in the function connect()?

Comment: I would recommend you reconsider the question whether you actually *need* to add a wrapper class for PDO. What additional functionality will your class provide that isn't already provided by PDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this:

```
$this->$con = new PDO(etc...
       ^---
```

`$con` is undefined in this context, which means you're doing the equivalent of `$this->null = new PDO ....`

Try `$this->con` instead. Note the lack of `$` on `con`.

Comment: This worked, however, now I have another error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DB_CONNECT::prepare() in get_all_products.php. So now it's complaining that prepare() is undefined, but isn't that a built-in function for PDO?

Comment: Will it be a good solution to add
public function prepare($z) {
        return $this->pdo->prepare($z);
    } 
to the DB_connect class?

Comment: because your DB handle is in `$db->con`. you have no `prepare` method defined in your own object, you're just embedding PDO inside, which means you need to talk to pdo: `$db->con->prepare`